# Why is the related post widget only appearing in the footer, but not the sidebar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a related post widget for my blogger blog, When I am installing the widget in footer it appears correctly but when I am trying to display it in sidebar noting is appearing on a blank widget appear. Why this occurs please help me. Can you please check the code and tell me if their is an error. see the [site](https://wishingfestivalritual.blogspot.com/2020/08/generate-xml-sitemap.html) where I am using it.
This I the code I am using:

```js
<!--RelatedPostsStarts-->
<script language='JavaScript'>
//<![CDATA[
var relatedTitles = new Array();
var relatedTitlesNum = 0;
var relatedUrls = new Array();

function related_results_labels(json) {
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
        var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
        relatedTitles[relatedTitlesNum] = entry.title.$t;
        for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
            if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                relatedUrls[relatedTitlesNum] = entry.link[k].href;
                relatedTitlesNum++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function removeRelatedDuplicates() {
    var tmp = new Array(0);
    var tmp2 = new Array(0);
    for(var i = 0; i < relatedUrls.length; i++) {
        if(!contains(tmp, relatedUrls[i])) {
            tmp.length += 1;
            tmp[tmp.length - 1] = relatedUrls[i];
            tmp2.length += 1;
            tmp2[tmp2.length - 1] = relatedTitles[i];
        }
    }
    relatedTitles = tmp2;
    relatedUrls = tmp;
}

function contains(a, e) {
    for(var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) if (a[j]==e) return true;
        return false;
}

function printRelatedLabels() {
    var r = Math.floor((relatedTitles.length - 1) * Math.random());
    var i = 0;
    document.write('<ul>');
    while (i < relatedTitles.length && i < 6) {
        document.write('<li><a href="' + relatedUrls[r] + '">' + relatedTitles[r] + '</a></li>');
        if (r < relatedTitles.length - 1) {
            r++;
        } else {
            r = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    document.write('</ul>');
}
//]]>
</script>
```

```css
#related-posts {clear: both;background-color:#000;}
#related-posts ul{margin: 20px 0; padding: 0;list-style: none;}
#related-posts ul li {border-top: 1px solid #333;border-bottom: 1px solid #111;}
#related-posts ul li:first-child {border-top: none;}
#related-posts ul li:last-child {border-bottom: none;}
#related-posts ul li a {padding: 10px;display: block;color: #222;text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer; -webkit-transition: padding-left 250ms ease-out; -moz-transition: padding-left 250ms ease-out; /* trans pattern: property duration timingMethod delay */}
#related-posts ul li a:hover {padding-left: 20px;}
```

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <div id='related-posts'>
        <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
            <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>
            </b:if>
            <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
                <script expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=related_results_labels&amp;max-results=5&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
            </b:if>
        </b:loop>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        var currentposturl=&quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;;
        var maxresults=5; // Increase To Show More Then 5 Related Post
        removeRelatedDuplicates();
        printRelatedLabels();
        </script>
    </div>
</b:if>
```

Comment: sorry for that but could you gave the answer